# Getting a python module to work with Python after installing module (and not re-installing python)

Tags: python, installation, pythonbrew, python-venv

I suppose this would apply to anyone using tools like: virtualenv, virtualenvwrapper, pythonbrew, pyenv, etc.

Let me give the use-case. I am using pythonbrew. I want to create a venv, but I get an Import Error saying that there is no "zlib".

So what I do is, I run this command (linux deb/ubuntu terminal):

```
sudo apt-get install zlib1g-dev
```

Now the only way I am aware of making sure that the python version I wanted to use with zlib will now work is to uninstall it and then reinstall it again (for anybody that wishes to know, it now works with zlib being recognized).

This takes a lot of time (installing) and makes me wonder what might happen if I have like 5 venvs with multiple setups, only to realize that I need some new module and have to delete my python version again (to reinstall it) and which may also break the 5 venvs (it may, but I'm not sure).

My question is, how could I make sure that the python version will acknowledge something like the zlib installation above without doing a complete re-install of python?

Is there something I could modify in any of the files or perhaps run some update command?